# Insert into - SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm working to push the contents of one table source (from a linked server) to an another table i.e. `dbo.dest`

```
insert into [dbo].[dest]
  select * 
  from OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER,'select * from source')
```

Source table has 50 columns.

Is there any way I can create the table (`dbo.dest`) dynamically for the columns for source?

Any input would be helpful.

Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, might work:

```
 select * into [dbo].[dest]
 from OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER,'select * from source')
```

NB [dbo].[dest] can't exist when you run this query.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
select *
into dbo.test
from OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER,'select * from source')
```

Comment: Works, as long as the destination table doesn't exist

Comment: @marc_s The OP explicitly says he wants to create the table.  That would imply that the table does not exist.